# RPM: invoking a macro with arguments from another macro with arguments

Tags: linux, macros, rpm, packaging

I would like to invoke an RPM macro taking an argument from another macro. In `m4`, this would be done trivially like this (just an example, not what I really want to do):

```
define(`path', `/mnt/$1/lib')
define(`mkd', `mkdir path($1)/stuff')
mkd(`usr')
=> mkdir /mnt/usr/lib/stuff
```

Or in `CPP` syntax:

```
#define path(x) /mnt/x/lib
#define mkd(x) mkdir path(x)/stuff
mkd(usr)
=> mkdir /mnt/usr/lib/stuff
```

The obvious equivalent in RPM (**broken!**) would be:

```
# THIS IS BROKEN
%define path() /mnt/%1/lib
%define mkd() mkdir %{path %1}/stuff
%mkd usr
```

But this **does not** work, RPM prints "*error: Too many levels of recursion in macro expansion. It is likely caused by recursive macro declaration.*"

I have made it "work" with the following code:

```
%define path() /mnt/%1/lib
%define mkd() mkdir %{expand:%%{path %1}}/stuff
%mkd usr
```

However I can't believe that this clumsy code would be the recommended way for doing this. Another approach that appears to work is using option arguments:

```
%define path(d:) /mnt/%{-d*}/lib
%define mkd(p:) mkdir %{path -d%{-p*}}/stuff
%mkd -p usr
```

But this works only because I used *different option characters*; if I use '`-d`' for both macros, it fails like the example above. I don't like this solution much either, because using options seems non-intuitive here.

What would be the preferred way to achieve the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

I found a more elegant solution. I don't understand why it works, and I'm not sure if it's generally applicable:

```
%define path() /mnt/%1/lib
%global mkd() mkdir %{path %%1}/stuff
%mkd usr
=> mkdir /mnt/usr/lib/stuff
```

It works only if `mkd` is define with `%global`. `path` can be define either with `%define` or `%global`. Also node the quoted percent character.

Comment: It works because %global is evaluated not when it is parsed (as %define) but in the time it is called.  Basicaly anytime you write %define you usually want to use %global.

Comment: @msuchy It's the other way around. `%define` macros are evaluated when used, `%global` when defined. That is why this works: the definition of `mkd` is frozen with the `path` already expanded, so no recursion happens when the argument is substituted.

Answer (score 1):

RPM handling of recursive macros is broken. As far as I was able to find out, there is no "recommended" way; this simply doesn't work and the workarounds you listed are as close as you're going to get.

Within RPM macro sets I've seen (including some within RPM itself), this is usually solved through conditional arguments: use `-p` option if supplied, `%1` otherwise.

```
%define path(p:) /mnt/%{-p:%{-p*}}%{!-p:%1}/lib
%define mkd(d:)  mkdir %{path -p %1}/stuff
echo "making path at %{path hello}"
%{mkd hello}
```

---

You can also use "non-function" definitions -- this is sort of what is going on in the `%define`/`%global` case.

```
%define _path /mnt/%1/lib
# note no parentheses at end of `_path`
%define path() %_path
%define mkd()  mkdir %{_path}/stuff
```

This way, the `%_path` macro is inlined into the `path()` and `mkd()` definitions and no recursion is happening.

This would not work if you wanted to use `%2` for the path, but because that is a different name, you can use it the old way ......... o_O

```
%define maketwo() mkdir %1; mkdir %{path %2}/stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem reported in this question is solved in recent versions of rpm, between 4.11 and 4.14.

```
~> rpm --version
RPM version 4.14.1
~> rpm --eval '
%define path() /mnt/%1/lib
%define mkd() mkdir %{path %1}/stuff
%define foo bar
%mkd %foo'

=> mkdir /mnt/bar/lib/stuff
```

With rpm 4.11, this fails with "too many levels of recursion", and the workaround of the previous answer (`%global mkd() mkdir %{path %%1}/stuff`) is necessary.